# Apache crashing when installing PHP

Tags: php, apache

Trying to get a fresh install of Apache (2.2.17) and PHP (5.3.4 VC6 x86 Thread Safe) running on Windows XP Sp2 ..

Apache installs and runs fine, until I install PHP .. I then try to restart the service and it crashes in Windows...

Here's what I get in the error.log ... Help! (FYI - don't want to use WAMP)

> Starting the Apache2.2 service The
>   Apache2.2 service is running. ]
>   Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) configured --
>   resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:32 2011] [notice]
>   Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:32 2011] [notice]
>   Parent: Created child process 1732
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:32 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Child process is running
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:32 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Acquired the start mutex.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:32 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Starting 64 worker
>   threads.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:32 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Starting thread to listen
>   on port 80.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:08:38 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:27 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:28 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/info.php
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:28 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:30 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/info.php
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:31 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:32 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:33 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:33 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:43 2011] [notice]
>   Parent: Received restart signal --
>   Restarting the server.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:43 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Exit event signaled. Child
>   process is ending.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:44 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Released the start mutex
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:45 2011] [notice]
>   Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) configured --
>   resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:45 2011] [notice]
>   Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:45 2011] [notice]
>   Parent: Created child process 5824
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:46 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: All worker threads have
>   exited.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:46 2011] [notice]
>   Child 1732: Child process is exiting
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:51 2011] [crit] (OS
>   6)The handle is invalid.  :
>   master_main: create child process
>   failed. Exiting.
>
> [Tue Jan 04 11:09:51 2011] [notice]
>   Parent: Forcing termination of child
>   process 36

EDIT

---

I restarted the machine and it seems to work now!  grrr

Comment: You will probably need to show how you activate PHP within Apache

Comment: Apache also crashes when you install PHP with all features selected, because of the dependencies. Install it as is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I Restarted the machine and it seemed to work .. go figure

Answer (score 0):

Found this bugtrack;
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52191

Could also be a rights issue or improper shutdown of previous processes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Xamp for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)?